# PHP Loop wont work

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, while-loop

I am trying to get values from an form with arrays them I need to get the ids from the bd to update, but it isnt working, maybe u give me an idea, I'll post the code, so u may understand. Thank you in advance for your help!

```
<?php

include "conecta.php";
include "verifica.php";



$sql1 = "SELECT idcategorias FROM categorias";
$res = mysql_query($sql1);
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
$gosma = $row["idcategorias"];
}

foreach ($_POST['ordem'] as $key => $value){


$sql = "UPDATE categorias SET ordem='$value' WHERE idcategorias='$gosma'";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Erro ao alterar") . mysql.error();
}

if($res) {
echo("<script>alert('DADOS ALTERADOS COM SUCESSO ');</script>");
echo "<meta HTTP-EQUIV='refresh' CONTENT='1;URL=lista_categorias.php'>";

 }

else{
echo("<script>alert('ORDEM INALTERADA, TENTE NOVAMENTE');</script>");
echo "<meta HTTP-EQUIV='refresh' CONTENT='1;URL=altera_ordem_categoria.php'>";
}

?>
```

AND THE FORM IS HERE

```
<form action="altera_ordem_cat.php" method="post">
<?php
include "conecta.php";
include "verifica.php";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM categorias ORDER BY ordem";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
while ($linha=mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
$linha[2] = $real;
?>

<tr>
<td><?=$linha['2']; echo "&#32;<input name='ordem[]' type='text' id='textfield'    size='2' maxlength='2' value=''/>" ?></td>
<td><?=$linha['1']; ?></td> 
</tr>

 <?php }?>


  </table>
  <br/>
  <table align="center">
  <tr>
 <td>
 <input type="submit" name="alterar" type="button" value="Alterar">
 </td>
 </tr>
  </table>
   </form>
```

Comment: Please clarify what is wrong.  What specific error are you getting and what are you expecting it to do?

Comment: What it is exactly you are trying to do here? What did you expect it to do? What did it do instead? What have you tried?

Comment: What are you *trying to do*? There are many problems with your code.

Comment: Show your form, at least the part where you should have several fields for "ordem" ($_POST['ordem']).

Comment: You need to specify the exact issue you're facing. Don't expect the people here to test the code for you and it's indeed difficult to test because doing so, requires relevant tables in the database which is not possible to create at a glance. So, be precise about your question.

Comment: I have categories from a website the should change order, from numbers that are previously assined for them, then I need to give an option to the user to change its order, so, I have a form that prints the current order, and then the user change the order assining the numbers in the form. What I need to do is update the database with the new order. I will post the form here to... Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your while cycle overwrites the `$row` each time. Don't you mean to do this?

```
$gosma = array();
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    $gosma[] = $row["idcategorias"];
}
```

You should always escape before inserting into a query:

```
$sql = "UPDATE categorias SET ordem='".mysql_real_escape_string($value)."' WHERE idcategorias='".mysql_real_escape_string($gosma)."'";
```

You should put the mysql_error inside the die function (and don't use dot in the name)

```
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Erro ao alterar: ".mysql_error());
```

---

What is it you're trying to do in this cycle?

```
foreach ($_POST['ordem'] as $key => $value) {   
    $sql = "UPDATE categorias SET ordem='$value' WHERE idcategorias='$gosma'";
    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Erro ao alterar") . mysql.error();
}
```

Don't you want something like this?

```
foreach ($_POST['ordem'] as $key => $value) {   
    $sql = "UPDATE categorias SET ordem='".mysql_real_escape_string($value)."' WHERE idcategorias='".mysql_real_escape_string($key)."'";
    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Erro ao alterar: ".mysql_error());
}
```

---

---

**EDIT**:

```
<form action="altera_ordem_cat.php" method="post">
  <table>
<?php
include "conecta.php";
include "verifica.php";
$sql = "SELECT idcategorias, ordem FROM categorias ORDER BY ordem";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

while ($linha = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
?>
  <tr>
    <td><input name='ordem[<?php echo $linha[0]; ?>]' type='text' id='textfield' size='2' maxlength='2' value='<?php echo $linha[1]; ?>'/></td>
    <td></td> 
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
  </table>
<!-- ........ -->
```

And afterwards:

```
<?php

include "conecta.php";
include "verifica.php";

foreach ($_POST['ordem'] as $key => $value) {   
  $sql = "UPDATE categorias SET ordem='".mysql_real_escape_string($value)."' ".
         "WHERE idcategorias='".mysql_real_escape_string($key)."'";
  $res = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Erro ao alterar: ".mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Czechnology, yes, but if I close the while after the database uptade, somehow, $row becomes 0 as a value, so it cant assign the $value to the id $gosma. Its not looping if I close it after the db update.

Comment: @Renato Ferreira, I think your form is also not good. You should write the field like this `<input name='ordem[<?php echo $linha[0]; ?>]' type="text" id="textfield" size="2" maxlength="2" value="<?php echo $linha[1]; ?>" />` (supposing that index 0 is where `idcategorias` is and 1 corresponds to `ordem`). Then you can use the cycle I posted in my answer.

Comment: this last example u gave should work fine but its not updating the db and returns array after the form is submited

Comment: @Renato Ferreira, it is *supposed* to return an array in the form of `idcategorias => ordem`. See my editted answer.

Comment: Well, I did try it here, but doesnt work either.As the original code I have posted the UPDATE at the db should be done on the lines of idcategorias wich I was retrieving from the bd with a while, but wasnt working at all.

Comment: Ok worked now! I did everything you said, I didnt realize the form was bad too. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
$gosma[] = $row["idcategorias"]; instead of $gosma = $row["idcategorias"];
```